# How can i optimized image for web on uploading on php script?

Tags: php

I am developing php web app where admin user can upload images on server. I want to optimize image for web on uploading, and maybe to resize it on specific dimensions. Is there any link or script to do this?

Comment: Have you read the docs on image processing? http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have imagemagick installed (replace #convert# with the path to your convert executable):

```
<?php
$cmd = '#convert# '.$file_name.' -interlace LINE -strip +repage ';
if($file_type == 'jpeg'){
    $cmd .= '-define jpeg:preserve-settings -quality 72 ';
}elseif($file_type == 'png'){
    $cmd .= '-define png:bit-depth 4 ';
}
$cmd .= $file_cache;
?>
```

or also

```
<?php
$cmd = '#convert# '.$file_name;
$cmd .= ' -resize "800x800>"';
$cmd .= ' -quality 50 '; //or 72 or whatever you need it to be
$cmd .= ' '.$file_cache;
?>
```

Then you execute `$cmd`

Answer (score -1):

There are several options for this: maybe something like [phpthumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) or you can use [imagemagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) and do it your self

I think it depends on how you want to manage such images...in *upload* time or when *displaying it*